# Limit of a derivative is 1/2

Tags: limits, derivatives

How do I show that 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow b} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{xn^x-bn^b}{n^x-n^b} = \frac{1}{2}$$
where n and b are constants and $n>1$.
I saw that it is 1/2 graphing it but I think i still don't have the necessary tools to prove it.

Comment: Right now I'd just take the derivative and then take the limit, (probably using L'Hopitals). Doesn't look like fun though, there might be a simpler way.

Comment: I tried doind that, but the derivative is really ugly and I didn't find any trivial  way to apply L'Hopital's

Comment: How about interchanging the derivative and limit operators first?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{xn^x-bn^b}{n^x-n^b} = \frac{(1+x\ln(n))n^x(n^x-n^b)-(xn^x-bn^b)\ln(n)n^x}{(n^x-n^b)^2}$$
$$=\frac{n^{2x}-n^{x+b}-x\ln(n)n^{x+b}+bn^{x+b}\ln(n)}{(n^x-n^b)^2}$$

$$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)h +\frac{1}{2}f''(a)h^2+o(h^2)$$

$$=n^x\frac{\ln(n)n^b(x-b)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)^2n^b(x-b)^2 + o((x-b)^2)-\ln(n)(x-b)n^{b}}{(n^x-n^b)^2}$$
$$=n^x\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)^2n^b(x-b)^2 + o((x-b)^2)}{(n^x-n^b)^2}$$
$$=n^x\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)^2n^b(x-b)^2 + o((x-b)^2)}{(\ln(n)n^b(x-b)+o(x-b))^2}$$
$$\sim_{x \to b} n^b\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)^2n^b(x-b)^2}{(\ln(n)n^b(x-b))^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: There might be a simpler way but it works